# Не работает скроллинг у QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Есть окно с кастомными виджетами-диаграммами и виджетами-временным-шкалами:
[image: Окно с диаграммами]
Изначально размер виджета-диграммы задаётся в конструкторе следующим образом относительно своего парента — скролла, в котором виджет находится:

```
setGeometry(0, 0,
                 max<int>(static_cast<int>(outputData->maxArrivingTime() / dialog->commonSAGridSpacing * dialog->commonSAScale) + 20,
                             parent->width()),
                 max<int>(static_cast<int>(outputData->outputSettings.flowQuantity * (rowHeight + 1)),
                             parent->height()));
```

Затем кнопками управления шагом сетки по времени (`gridaSpacing`) и масштабом в пикселях (`scale`) диаграмма перерисовывается, ей задаётся геометрия в методе перерисовки:

```
setGeometry(0, 0, 
                 max<int>(static_cast<int>(outputData->maxArrivingTime() / dialog->commonSAGridSpacing * dialog->commonSAScale) + 20,
                                         dynamic_cast<QScrollArea *>(parent())->width()),
                 max<int>(static_cast<int>(outputData->outputSettings.flowQuantity * (rowHeight + 1)),
                                         dynamic_cast<QScrollArea *>(parent())->height()));
```

Постепал с точками останова, геометрия виджета становится больше геометрии скролла, паренты указаны аккуратно, однако виджет не скроллится, скролл-бары не появляются, хотя `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded)`.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально не было у scroll area метода `setWidget()`, но был руками у виджета установлен parent — нужная scroll area. Метод `setWidget()` уведомляет родителя о том, что ребёнок изменил размер, заставляя родителя анализировать размер ребёнка относительно своего.

Также в методе перерисовки был метод `setGeomtry` был заменён на `resize`.